# My circular arrays don't array

Tags: modifiers

My Array Modifier seems to make fine arrays in Constant Offset or Relative Offset. However when I try to use Object Offset nothing gets arrayed.  I have followed every tutorial I can find to see if I am missing a step; no luck.  I have tried on several machines; they all behave the same.  When I rotate the Empty it spins all day long while the object remains still and never produces any meshes. The object and the Empty have the same Location, Rotation, and Scale, but do not seem to be associating with each other. Using 2.79b on a Windows 10 platform.

Comment: From the information provided, it's hard to provide any help other than a bunch of guesses of what's going on. Could you please provide either a screenshot of the scene&modifier settings or a `.blend` file with the problem?

Comment: You can upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Thank you, thibsert! Had everything right EXCEPT the checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that :

- Object Offset is checked
- Under Object Offset, the Empty is selected (either via the object list, or via the picker)
- Count isn't set to 1.